# How to get PCB assembled

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I have a couple of questions regarding getting a PCB developed. I have used EasyEDA to develop a PCB schematic (auto-routing included.)

How can I find the availability of parts? For example, I have a Bluetooth module and I expect some modules are more available than others.

When reaching out to a PCB manufacturer/assembler, do they retrieve the components for you, or do PCB assembly companies have a defined list of components you can use on your PCB?

Comment: I'm not understanding the relevance of your paragraph about a Bluetooth module.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm using the AT-09 module, I'm wondering if there might be a different module that have more available (higher supply) on the market

Comment: I don't see the relevance of this to your question at all.

Answer (score 2):

> When reaching out to a PCB manufacturer/assembler, do they retrieve the components for you? Or do PCB assembly companies have a defined list of components you can use on your PCB?

Both. Usually, they have a catalog of standard components – mostly passives, but also standard ICs, connectors, LEDs – that you can directly use in your project, often at good prices (because the boardhouse orders 100,000 of them, and you would order 20).

The more professional board houses also offer that you can send components directly to them, or that they can order for you (from a selection of distributors). Cost varies greatly, but in general, it's possible. Usually, the most expensive solution is sending them the components to use. (That's the most "manual" work. If they just have to order 20 additional components from digikey, they don't have to do any extra sorting, bookkeeping, dealing with suboptimal packaging…)

Answer (score 1):

You have to read assembler rules. Each assembler have different rules like:

- Have warehouse of 10k components that they readily have.
- Have ability to order required components for your PCB.
- Have ability to receive a package with components from you.

As well, they have different abilities like:

- Automatic mount surface components (is cheap)
- Only manual mount through hole components (is expensive)
- Ability to mount components only on single side of PCB.
- Ability to mount components on both sides of PCB.